# VLAN and Active Directory: complementary or substitute?

Tags: networking, active-directory, ldap, vlan, openldap

I recently encountered a network design that heavily implements VLANs but does not make use of a dedicated identity and access management system such as Active Directory or OpenLDAP. And yet another design plans to use Active Directory but with plain tree-like subnetting for the network. My questions:

- Is VLAN the only way to go for better-managed network? Is it always a best practice for network design for big companies?
- I was once in a university that uses AD and (I think) VLANs. Is it a "standard
  design" when we want to ensure security and good user management?
- Is it common (these days, in a big enterprise setup) to have AD/OpenLDAP without
  VLAN? Or, conversely, VLAN without AD/OpenLDAP?
- Are VLAN and AD/OpenLDAP two *entirely orthogonal notions?* And hence complementary?  If so, I guess the teams of the two design above need to talk.

Further questions:

- When using VLANs, it is customary separate VLAN networks based on departments (Accounting, HR, etc). Add AD to it, should we make different domains, based (also) on departments?
- How about designing AD based on buildings and simlarly for the VLANs?
  In short, how to best implements subnetting, VLANs and AD together?

Any insights, tips, links, or advice is welcome.

Comment: Completely different concepts.

Comment: This is like asking if your orange juice has anything to do with your belt sander.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is VLAN the only way to go for better-managed network? Is it always a best practice for network design for big companies?

They're for whenever they make sense at any size.

> I was once in a university that uses AD and (I think) VLANs. Is it a "standard design" when we want to ensure security and good user management?

VLANs by themselves aren't security boundaries, just broadcast boundaries. However, by separating logical groups into VLANs, you give your self the opportunity to place ACLs between them, should you desire.

Of course AD is for "good" user management. It's an authorization and authentication service. That's what it was designed for.

> Is it common (these days, in a big enterprise setup) to have AD/OpenLDAP without VLAN? Or, conversely, VLAN without AD/OpenLDAP?

No. Large enterprises usually make use of VLANs. Though, the reason has nothing to do with AD or OpenLDAP.

> Are VLAN and AD/OpenLDAP two entirely orthogonal notions? And hence complementary? If so, I guess the teams of the two design above need to talk.

Why would the two "design teams" as you put it, need to talk? One works at Layer 2, the other works at Layer 7. They're entirely unrelated. Why would a switch port configuration have anything to do with an authentication server?

> When using VLANs, it is customary separate VLAN networks based on departments (Accounting, HR, etc). Add AD to it, should we make different domains, based (also) on departments?

For VLANs, maybe depending on the environment. For AD, no. It's not best practice to use child domains unless you need to introduce a hard management boundary between AD resources. In most cases, child domains are not a recommended design. One domain to rule them all.

> How about designing AD based on buildings and simlarly for the VLANs? In short, how to best implements subnetting, VLANs and AD together?

Implement VLANs based on your Layer 2 switching needs. Implement AD according to your AD needs. Really, as long as the client machines connected the the different VLANs can communicate with AD, there's nothing more to think about.

---

It seems you have some silly idea that VLANs and AD somehow directly complement each other. They are entirely independent. In many organizations you see both deployed, because they are both industry-standard, useful technologies. That does not mean that they are somehow star-crossed lovers that must coexist, lest the other die of a broken heart.

AD does authorization and authentication. VLANs do logical layer 2 separation on a single piece of switching hardware. The two are as related as a boot and a salt shaker.